# SQL Parameter count mismatch on QTableView

Tags: c++, sql, sqlite, qt5, qtableview

I have a GUI composed of:

N.1 GraphicsView

N.1 QTableView

N.1 dialog that opens up as needed by the user after doubleclicking on each row of the QTableView

I can capture features on the QGraphicsView with the mouse click. After the feature is drawn I right click and open up a dialog like the one in the figure:

[image: Dialog]

After hitting accept: I register the feature as the row index of the QTableView as shown below:

[image: Dialog_after_accepting]

If I doubleclick on each row I am able to open again the same dialog with the information previously saved. I do that because I may need to change the name of the image and call it differently.

The problem I currently have is that I ma receiving a weird `Parameter count mismatch` from the compiler and I don't understand why and it should be due to `QSQLITE`

Below is what I am trying to do along with the most important part of the code:

**parameters.h**

```
typedef struct Param
{
    int mId;
    QString mName;
    QByteArray mSave;
} Param;

class Parameters
{
public:
    Parameters() = default;
    Parameters(Param newdata);
    Parameters(int id, const QString &name, const QByteArray &save);
    int id() const { return data.mId; }
    QString name() const {return data.mName; }
    QByteArray save() const {return data.mSave; }
    Param getData() const { return data; }
    void setData(Param ndat) { data = ndat; }
private:
    Param data;
};
```

**parameters.cpp**

```
#include "parameters.h"
Parameters::Parameters(Param newdata) {
    data = newdata;
}
Parameters::Parameters(int id, const QString &name,
                               const QByteArray &save) {
    data.mId = id;
    data.mSave = save;
    data.mName = name;
}
```

the database is set in the following **dataleftcamera.h** part:

```
public:
    explicit dataLeftCamera(QObject *parent = nullptr);
    bool addItem(Parameters* mParameters);
    bool updateItem(int itemId, Parameters* mParameters);
    QSqlDatabase getDatabase();
private:
    QString mError;
    QSqlDatabase mDatabaseLeft;
```

The table is initiated here on **dataleftcamera.cpp** and here is where the compiler is giving the `Parameter count mismatch` error specifically on the function `updateItem`

```
#define CREATE_TABLE \
    " CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS leftCamTable" \
    " (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL" \
    ", name TEXT NOT NULL" \
    ", save BLOB NOT NULL)"

dataLeftCamera::dataLeftCamera(QObject *parent) : QObject (parent)
{}

bool dataLeftCamera::addItem(Parameters *mParameters)
{
    QSqlQuery qry;
    qry.prepare("INSERT INTO leftCamTable (name, save)"\
                " VALUES (?,?)");
    qry.addBindValue(mParameters->name());
    qry.addBindValue(mParameters->save());

    bool ok = qry.exec();
    if(!ok) {
        mError = qry.lastError().text();
        qDebug() << mError;
    }
}

bool dataLeftCamera::updateItem(int itemId, Parameters *mParameters)
{
    QSqlQuery qry;
    qry.prepare(" UPDATE lefCamTable SET " \
                " name = ?," \
                " save = ?" \
                " WHERE id = ?");
    qry.addBindValue(mParameters->name());
    qry.addBindValue(mParameters->save());
    qry.addBindValue(itemId);

    bool ok = qry.exec();
    if(!ok) {
        mError = qry.lastError().text();
        qDebug() << mError;
    }
}
```

On the **mainwindow.cpp** is the part where I update the item after I `doubleclick` on the row to change the name of the image and accept again the modification:

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    mDatabaseLeftCamera = new dataLeftCamera(this);
    mModelLeftCamera = nullptr;
    mModelLeftCamera = new QSqlTableModel(this);
    ui->tableView->setModel(mModelLeftCamera);
    connect(ui->tableView, SIGNAL(doubleClicked(QModelIndex)),
            this, SLOT(onTableClick(QModelIndex)));
// temporary folder
    temporaryFolder = "/home/name/Desktop/tempDBFolder/tmp.db";
    QFile dbRem(temporaryFolder);
    dbRem.remove();
    mDatabaseLeftCamera->inizializationDatabaseLeftCamera(temporaryFolder);
    mDatabaseLeftCamera->configurationDatabaseLeftCamera();
    mModelLeftCamera = new QSqlTableModel(this, mDatabaseLeftCamera->getDatabase());
    mModelLeftCamera->setTable("leftCamTable");
    mModelLeftCamera->select();
    ui->tableView->setModel(mModelLeftCamera);
    ui->tableView->showColumn(true);
}

// opening the dialog for the first time after capturing the image
void MainWindow::contextMenuEvent(QContextMenuEvent *event)
{
    // operations

    Param result = d.getData();
    Parameters* param = new Parameters(result);
    mDatabaseLeftCamera->addItem(param);
    mModelLeftCamera->select();
    ui->tableView->show();
}

// This is the doubleclick that re-opens the small dialog to change the name of the feature

void MainWindow::onTableClick(const QModelIndex &index)
{
    int row = index.row();
    Param currentData;
    int ItemId = index.sibling(row, 0).data().toInt();
    currentData.mName = index.sibling(row, 1).data().toString();
    currentData.mSave = index.sibling(row, 2).data().toByteArray();
    QPixmap iconPix;
    if(!iconPix.loadFromData(index.sibling(row, 2).data().toByteArray())) {
    }
    clipSceneDialog d(this);
    d.show();
    d.setData(currentData);
    d.setImage(iconPix.toImage());

    if(d.exec() == QDialog::Rejected) {
        return;
    } else {
        //
    }
    Param result = d.getData();
    Parameters* param = new Parameters(result);
    mDatabaseLeftCamera->updateItem(ItemId,param);
    mModelLeftCamera->select();
    ui->tableView->show();
}
```

For completeness see the error the compiler is giving if that helps:

[image: compiler_error]
I am sorry if this is trivial but I checked the `updateItem(ItemId,param)` 
and thanks for shedding light on this.

Comment: For me, these messages in your last image look like run-time messages but not compiler errors. I'm not experienced in SQL but it looks like your SQL retrieval is not correct. Btw. please, copy/paste console output and other log text as text instead of making snaphots.

Comment: OT.: Your app. snapshots let me think, you're struggling with encoding issues. (I mean the funny glyphs before and after `PNG` in your table.) Concerning encoding issues, there is a nice intro: [About Unicode and Character Sets](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/). `QString` has a lot of `to` and `from` functions to fix this - you just have to use them right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try and add some debug printing. Especially for the parameters that you add to the prepared statement. `qry.addBindValue` converts your value to a `QVariant`. Based on the [documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qvariant.html) `QVariants` become `NULL` when they contain no data:

```
QVariant x(QString());
// x.isNull() == true
```

In case there is a problem retrieving your parameters, this could explain the violation of the `NOT NULL` constraints.

Comment: @Scheff - Thanks for your comment and for taking the time to read the question! The glyphs that you see before and after the `PNG` it was intentional. The reason is that the user may have hundred of images and to scroll down to see all of them freezes the GUI and it takes a long time to get to the end. So a good (not elegant though) way of going quickly through the images was not to save the image. If there is a more elegant and efficient way please let me know. Or if you know of existing examples please share them as it would be helpful to see.

Comment: Thank you too @jschwing to take time to read through the question! Apparently this `count mismatch` it seem to be due to the fact that the `itemId` inside the `onTableClick` function is different from the row where the user `doubleclick` inside the `QTableView`. I took a [print screen](https://i.imgur.com/LmzrLeU.png) of the debugger. Is [this](https://i.imgur.com/uWe9c01.png) helpful too?. I don't understand how though.

Comment: Thanks @ jschwing for suggesting to use `QVariant x(QString());` it worked. What happened was that as soon as I created a reference, default parameters where passed right away. So the `nameLineEdit` had already something and violated the `NOT NULL` constraint. I will mark your answer as correct!